# How to refresh the table view when we scroll up

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

Can we implement pull to refresh feature on a custom view controller which has tableviewcontroller. My view controller is not a table view controller, i have a tableviewcontroller on UIView and I want to refresh this tableview on pulling the screen down. How can I implement this feature.

i tried with github examples but  no luck...if you know plesae provide me some sample code than that will help for me.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Here is the good example of iphone -pull-to-refresh tableview](http://blog.leahculver.com/2010/12/iphone-pull-to-refresh.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rakesh...that example is for tableview as i mentioned my viewcontroller is the UIViewcontrollertype...

Comment: so you have to add delegate methods of uitableview.

Comment: i know you are new so afraid of convert code from UITableViewController to UIViewcontrollertype. but try it you can do it. u just write all delegate and datasorse method of uitableview. and implement delegate.

Comment: Thank you...implemented all the datasource and delegate methods...but in the example you have provided to me they are superclassed the pullrefreshviewcontroller...but from my viewcontroller how can i do that....

Comment: you have to write all methods of PullRefreshTableViewController.h,PullRefreshTableViewController.m in ur viewcontrollers class.

Answer (score -1):

It may help you

[tableView reloadData];